# Passing parameters from Controller to View in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, controller

I've been working a lot lately with Ruby on Rails in Linux and now I need to create a web page in Windows.

I'm having problems with passing parameters from a Controller to a View. I want to create a list of users in the method "Index" and show that list on its view. Could anyone please explain me which is the correct way to do this *without setting my attributes "private"*? Maybe the answer is as simple as: it's impossible. For the moment I'll wait until someone tells me so.

I have a Model called "User", a Controller called "UsersController" and finally a View called "Users".

---

The code inside my Model is:

```
public class User
    {
        // Atributos
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String lastName;

        //Constructor
        public User(int id,String name, String lastname)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
            this.lastName = lastname;
        }

        //métodos
        public void setName(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
```

### (the same with the others attributes)

Then, here it's the code inside my Controller:

---

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<User> usersList = new List<User>();
            User user1 = new User(1,"Lihuen","Figueroa");
            User user2 = new User(2,"Solana", "Pachiorquevich");
            User user3 = new User(3,"Vicente", "Corrao");

            usersList.Add(user1);
            usersList.Add(user2);
            usersList.Add(user3);

            return View();
        }
```

---

And here it's the code in my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PruebaDeInterfaz.Models.User>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Users list</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>User name</th>
        <th>User lastname</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: You need to return the model to the view - `return View(usersList);` And your view should be named `Index.cshtml` (the same as the method) but if its not, then you also need to specify the view name - `return View("Users", usersList);`

Comment: Note you model also needs properties to bind to (or at least public fields). You model should simply be `public class User { public int Id { get; set; } public string Name { get; set; } public string LastName { get; set; } }` (plus the constructor if you want, but you also need a parameterless constructor if you want to use that model for editing data)

Comment: Hi, Stephen!

If I don't get it wrong then if I return my usersList to my view, once there I should be able to call my variable "usersList" by just typing it, isn't that correct? 
I've been used to setting all my attributes as private when creating desktop apps in Java, that's why I wanted to keep them private here. The real thing is that setting my attributes as public the thing works! Isn't that a bad habit tough?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If linked duplicate is not enough - search https://www.bing.com/search?q=mvc+Passing+parameters+from+Controller+to+View+in+C%23 and check out some tutorial https://www.asp.net/mvc... than [edit] post to clarify how your problem is unique.

Comment: @Xbmxpx - In the view, it would be `@foreach (var item in Model) { <td>@Model.LastName</td>` etc (and no, it not bad - they must be public)

Comment: Stephen: Ok! I'll leave them public.
Alexei: Thanks for giving me the link to an official ASP.NET guide. I'll read it to find out if I can solve my problem.